# How to select an appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with jQuery & Javascript. I'm trying to create an interactive sea with fishes etc.

I'm randomly placing fish div's on the page at random positions with the following code:

```
$newfish = $("<div id='fishToLeft'></div>").css({
    'left': randomX + 'px',
    'top': randomY + 'px',
}) 

$newfish.appendTo('#sea');
```

The images of the fish are configured in the CSS.

Now I want to animate those divs (it appends around 20 fish), but I can't figure out how to select the appended fish divs (fishToLeft & fishToRight).

Can anyone help me?

**SOLVED!** Instead of using the same id for all the fishes, I used the same class, now it works.

**Thanks for all the quick answers.**

Comment: ``document.getElementById('sea').querySelectorAll("*");``? Not sure of jQuery equivelant-- I think it's ``$("#sea").children();``.

Comment: You already have the element in `$newfish`

Comment: I think you should not be giving same ids to all your fishes

Comment: same ids are used. That might cause the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class not an id, because ids should be unique.

```
$newfish = $("<div class='fish'></div>").css({
```

Select by class:

```
$('.fish');
```

Alternatively, if only fish exist as children, then just select children:

```
$('#sea').children();
```

---

By storing the fish references in an array, you can avoid re-selecting them:

```
var fish = [];
// in your loop
fish.push($newfish);
```

Do something with each fish:

```
$.each(fish, function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this code is that you have multiple elements with the same id which is wrong. I would use `class` or custom attributes instead. Eg, with `class` selector:

```
$newfish = $("<div class='fishToLeft'></div>").css({
    'left': randomX + 'px',
    'top': randomY + 'px',
}) 

$newfish.appendTo('#sea'); 

var $fishesToLeft = $(".fishToLeft"); // array of elements/fishes to left
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it from id to class and it works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newfish = $("<div class='fish'></div>").css({
     'left': randomX + 'px',
     'top': randomY + 'px',
})
```

Let's say you want it on click event, then:

```
$(".fish").on("click", function(){
    var myFish = $(this);
})
```

`myFish` will contain the clicked element

Answer (score 0):

An `id` is for a single, unique element on the page.

Consequently, `fishToLeft` and `fishToRight` are not `ids` but `classes`.

So, you need to use:

```
<div class="fishToLeft"></div>
<div class="fishToRight"></div>
```

Later, when you want to want to select all the fish, you can use:

```
var fishesToLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('fishToLeft'); 
var fishesToRight = document.getElementsByClassName('fishToRight');
```

Comment: Thanks, I indeed changed it to classes instead of id's!